# Как сделать синий прямоугольник под текстом

Tags: img, blocks

Привет, надо сделать как на изображении, я пробовала при помощи свойства after, но оно не работает, что я неправильно делаю?

```css
.about__mission{
 padding-top: 89px;
}

.about__mission__left{
 float: left;
 width: 411px;
 height: 344px;
}

h3{
 font-size: 22px;
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3:after{
 margin-top: 13px;
 height: 3px;
 width: 72px;
 background: #4e8598;
}

p{
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: lighter;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 word-spacing: 0.2em;
 padding-top: 45px;
}
p + p{
 padding-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about__mission">
     <div class="about__mission__left">
      <h3>О Миссии</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, culpa assumenda maxime soluta deleniti! Molestias, aliquam nostrum? Hic labore molestias, voluptate, dicta earum facere quibusdam, fugit quas quia accusamus officia.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex doloribus repellendus, aliquid rerum ratione quidem dolore fugit consectetur iusto alias a numquam commodi, eaque praesentium debitis at id minima fugiat.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для псевдоэлементов [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::after), [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::before) нужен обязательный параметр (можно и пустой):

```
content: "";
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

```
h3:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;

    margin-top: 13px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 72px;
    background: #4e8598;
}
```